# layout divs in bootstrap

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I am using bootstrap for my web application.I want my divs to be displayed as below:

[image: required layout]

my html is as follows:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-12 col-sm-12 mb-4">
    <!--content-->
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-6 mb-4">
    <!-content-->
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-12 col-sm-12 mb-4">
    <!--content-->
</div>
```

But the output displayed is as follows:

[image: current output]

How can i change the html so that it can be displayed in the required format

Comment: that feel when people don't use css grid

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To achieve that you should right row column inside column try this

```
<div class="container border border-primary">
<div class="row border border-primary">
    <div class="border border-primary col-lg-8 col-md-12 col-sm-12" style="height:200px">
        <div class="row border border-secondary">
            <div class="border border-secondary col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12" style="height:100px">
                <!--content for 1-->
            </div>
            <div class="border border-secondary col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12" style="height:100px">
                <!--content for 2-->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="border border-primary col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-6" style="height:200px">
        <!-content for 3-->
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to check that your col's add up to 12, looks like some of your responsive selectors such as `col-md-12` were causing the issue. Here's a working demo:

```css
.col-4, .col-8 > .row{border: 3px solid black; padding: 30px; }
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-8">
    <div class="row">
      <!--content-->
      col-8
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <!--content-->
      col-8
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-4">
    <div class="row">
      col-4
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Please refer to the [Bootstrap docs on Grid System for more info](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/)

Answer (score 1):

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid #3d3d3d;
  padding: 5px;
}
// Dont consider this css
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">col-md-12</div>
        <div class="col-md-12">col-md-12</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">col-md-4</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Nice, maybe consider changing the `col-md-x` to `col-x` so that when OP runs the code snippet they can see a non-stacked example in their browser